# Explain x => x.ToString() //simplify so many calls

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, lambda

In a [question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033#9099) I find the following coding tip:-

2) simple lambdas with one parameter:

```
x => x.ToString() //simplify so many calls
```

As someone who has not yet used 3.0 I don't really understand this tip but it looks interesting so I would appreciate an expantion on how this simplifies calls with a few examples.

I've researched lambdas so I **think** I know what they do, however I **may** not fully understand so a **little** unpacking might also be in order.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you need to create an instance of a delegate which has a single parameter, lambda expressions allow you to create that delegate "inline" in a very concise manner. For instance, here's code to find a particular person in a list, by their name:

```
List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
// [..] Populate list here
Person jon = list.Find(p => p.Name == "Jon");
```

In C# 2.0 you could use an anonymous method which was a little bit more longwinded, but not *too* bad:

```
List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
// [..] Populate list here
Person jon = list.Find(delegate(Person p) { return p.Name == "Jon"; });
```

In C# 1.0 you'd have to create a whole extra method. In addition, if you wanted to parameterise it, you'd have to create a different type, whereas anonymous methods and lambda expressions capture their executing environment (local variables etc) so they act like closures:

```
public Person FindByName(List<Person> list, String name)
{
    return list.Find(p => p.Name == name); // The "name" variable is captured
}
```

There's more about this in [my article about closures](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx).

While passing delegates into methods isn't terribly common in C# 2.0 and .NET 2.0, it's a large part of the basis of LINQ - so you tend to use it a lot in C# 3.0 with .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 2):

This basically expands to:

```
private string Lambda(object x) {
  return x.ToString();
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought.

Where does it help over calling ToString directly?

Comment: All by itself it doesn't.  It depends on the context you use it in.

Comment: David: Suppose you want to transform a list of integers to a list of strings. You can write a generalised transformation routine, but it needs a delegate to apply to *each* value in the list - and lambda expressions make it easier to specify that delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with C# 2.0 anonymous methods? These two calls are equivalent (assuming SomeMethod accepts a delegate etc):

```
SomeMethod(x => x.ToString());

SomeMethod(delegate (SomeType x) { return x.ToString();});
```

I know which I'd rather type...

Answer (score 0):

```
string delegate(TypeOfX x)
{
  return x.ToString();
}
```